# one collider for 2 combined object

Tags: unity, collision-detection, collider

I have an obstacle that composed of 2 game object, but when the player collides it, it gets in OnTriggerEnter twice when the obstacle have 2 different collider, which is what it should be, of course. However, I couldnt find a solution for it, How can define one collider for both object properly? Because one collider does not fit for my shape.. if you can answer asap, I will be appreciated, thanks in advance :))[image]

Comment: The correct solution here is to use two colliders, and not write code that gets broken by two OnTriggerEnter messages. Since we can't see your code, we can't yet advise on how to fix your mistakes there.

Comment: @DMGregory actually the code has nothing, in OnTriggerEnter, just printing message on console to see how many times the player got damage. And if this object has different colliders one for Capsule and one for Capsule (1), when the player goes through on the center of obstacle, it prints the damage message twice. I didnt use blender, but, as I see people design objects and colliders by this program. But I just want to know is there way of handling colliders in unity :(

Comment: @DMGregory I mean, in script, maybe I can control OnTriggerEnter with bool value, like make it true if gets in once so that doesnt get in again, then in OnTriggerExit make it false for the following collisions bla bla.. But I think it is not a good way

Comment: Would you like to edit your question to show your code and ask for a better way?

Comment: @DMGregory ok, i will try